# Clojure Minesweeper from scratch

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, minesweeper

In order to exercise and learn Clojure, I decided to write a simple Minesweeper game from scratch. I'd consider myself as a Clojure novice and would be thankful if somebody could do a review or give me feedback on the code.

The full repository can be found [here](https://github.com/u6f6o/minesweeper) but I'd be also happy if somebody could have a look on the core functionalities at least:

**board.clj**

```
(ns minesweeper.board
  (:use [clojure.pprint]))


(defn empty-board
  "Create a rectangular empty board of
  the specified with and height"
  [w h]
  (vec (repeat w (vec (repeat h {})))))


(defn to-coords
  "Transform the board cells into coordinates"
  ([board]
   (to-coords board (constantly true)))
  ([board pred]
   (let [w (count board)
         h (count (first board))]
     (for [x (range w) y (range h) :when (pred (get-in board [x y]))]
       [x y]))))


(defn neighbour-cells
  "Locate neighbour cells based on coordinates [x y],
  respecting board width and height"
  [board [x y]]
  (let [w (count board)
        h (count (first board))]
    (for [dx (map (partial + x) [-1 0 1])
          dy (map (partial + y) [-1 0 1])
          :when (and (or (not= x dx) (not= y dy))
                     (> w dx -1)
                     (> h dy -1))]
      [dx dy])))


(defn warnings-freq [board]
  "Count the number of nearby mines"
  (let [mines (to-coords board :mine)
        warnings (mapcat (partial neighbour-cells board) mines)]
    (frequencies
     (remove (set mines) warnings))))


(defn random-mines
  [board start-pos]
  (-> (set (to-coords board))
      (disj start-pos)
      (shuffle)))


(defn place-mines
  "Place n mines randomly on the board"
  [board mine-count start-pos]
  (let [mines (take mine-count
                    (random-mines board start-pos))]
    (reduce
     (fn [m k]
       (assoc-in m k {:mine true}))
     board
     mines)))


(defn place-warnings
  "Place warnings on a mines' neighbour cells"
  [board]
  (let [mine-counts (warnings-freq board)]
    (reduce-kv
     (fn [m k v]
       (assoc-in m k {:warn v}))
     board
     mine-counts)))


(defn explore-field
  "Explore single field on the board"
  [board coords]
  (update-in board coords conj {:explored true}))


(defn handle-flag
  "Handles set and remove of a flag"
  [board coords]
  (update-in board coords
             #(assoc % :flag (not (:flag %)))))


(defn game-started?
  "At least one field explored?"
  [board]
  (pos? (count (to-coords board :explored))))


(defn game-lost?
  "Any mine exploded?"
  [board]
  (letfn [(pred [m] (and (:mine m) (:explored m)))]
    (pos? (count (to-coords board pred)))))


(defn game-won?
  "All fields cleared?"
  [board]
  (letfn [(pred [m] (or (:mine m) (:explored m)))]
    (= (to-coords board pred)
       (to-coords board))))
```

**game.clj**

```
(ns minesweeper.game
  (:require [minesweeper.board :as board]
            [minesweeper.dispatch :as disp]))


(def levels { :beginner     { :rows 8,  :cols 8,  :mines 10 }
              :intermediate { :rows 16, :cols 16, :mines 40 }
              :expert       { :rows 30, :cols 16, :mines 99 }})

(def ^:private level (atom {}))
(def ^:private board (atom []))


(defn- new-game
  [data]
  (let [new-level (:level data)]
    (do
      (reset! level new-level)
      (reset! board (board/empty-board
                     (:rows new-level)
                     (:cols new-level)))
      (disp/fire :game-initialized data))))


(defn- start-game
  [board mine-count start-pos]
  (-> board
      (board/place-mines mine-count start-pos)
      (board/place-warnings)))


(defn- explore
  [board data]
  (let [mine-count (:mines (:level data))
        position   (vector (:row data) (:col data))]
    (if (not (board/game-started? board))
      (-> board
          (start-game mine-count position)
          (board/explore-field position))
      (board/explore-field board position))))


(defn- explore-field
  [data]
  (let [board (swap! board explore data)
        attrs (get-in board (vector (:row data) (:col data)))
        data  (assoc data :attrs attrs)]
    (cond
     (board/game-won? board)   (disp/fire :game-won data)
     (board/game-lost? board)  (disp/fire :game-lost (assoc data :board board))
     :else                     (disp/fire :uncover-field data))))


(defn- handle-flag
  [data]
  (let [position (vector (:row data) (:col data))]
    (do
      (swap! board (partial board/handle-flag) position)
      (disp/fire :uncover-field data))))


(disp/register :explore-field #'explore-field)
(disp/register :handle-flag #'handle-flag)
(disp/register :new-game #'new-game)
```

Comment: There's no need to use `do` under `let`, `let` has implicit `do`.

Comment: Since it appears a few times, I might define something like `(def position (juxt :row :col))` so you can just say `(position data)` instead of `(vector (:row data) (:col data))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is excellent. You have nice small functions, intent is clear, and the docstrings are helpful.

These are very minor suggestions:

```
(update-in board coords
         #(assoc % :flag (not (:flag %)))
```

Might be slightly more obvious as

```
(update-in board (conj coords :flag) not))
```

or

```
(update-in board coords update :flag not)
```

update is 1.7 only, but you could also use update-in [:flag]

I think this `pred` would be better promoted to a defn, and perhaps called something like `boom`

```
(letfn [(pred [m] (and (:mine m) (:explored m)))]
```

(especially since it is repeated 2x)

`(disp/fire)` might just be a multimethod?